# Visual Studio underline method when returning an object

Tags: c++, object, methods, reference, return

i am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and i want to create a class to read .ini files in C++. It is not hard for me but Visual underline method when it return reference to an object and the error message is not clear for me so I need some help.

I have two class. One, Tokenizer, which read .ini files and the second, Token, which represent one token like [Somethink].

In Tokenizer i created a method to add new Tokens to the std::list when there are found in the ini file.

```
Token Tokenizer::addToken(string name){
    Token newToken(name);
    data.push_back(newToken);
    return newToken;
}
```

I need that reference to add pairs key->value to it later. This is the contructor of Token:

```
Token::Token(string tokenName){
    name = tokenName;
}
```

And everything should by ok but it's not. Visual Studio underline the word *addToken* in the code above saying that:

> Error: declaration is incompatible with "error-type> 
>   Tokenizer::addToken(std::string name)".

But the declaration is

```
Token Tokenizer::addToken(string name);
```

and class Token is also defined so it makes no sense to me. What is interesting when i change the type of returned value to VOID and remove the return instruction then everything is ok.

Please help. This is my first contact with references and Object programming in C++.

Comment: Your Token class should be declared before your Tokenizer class for this to work. Are you doing that? And looks like you're `using namespace std;` - try to avoid that too; if you're having type problems, use the `std::` prefix on all the objects of that namespace.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. I wroted class Token under the class Tokenizer. After i swaped that two class then everything start to work correct.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Edit** it turns out this was not the problem after all - it just could have been. Next time, prefer to post a *minimal working example* from the original code, not just some selected quotes.

This would be easier if you showed more code. Using my psychic debugging abilities, I'm going to guess that `Token` is a nested class/struct. I.e., you need to define it like

```
Tokenizer::Token Tokenizer::addToken(string name){
     Token newToken(name);
     data.push_back(newToken);
     return newToken;
}
```

I've guessed the namespace qualification to be Tokenizer::Token (but it might need to be something else)

**Note** also that it is *not* necessary to fully qualify the nested types (if they would be locally visible from withing `Tokenizer`) for

- method parameters
- the method body

Just the return type needs full qualification, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the declared the method in class `Token` as

```
class Tokenizer
{
  ...
  void addToken(string);
  ...
}
```

You need to change that to match your actual intended signature.

Comment: No. I wrote that the declaration is _Token Tokenizer::addToken(string name);_

Comment: @Elektryk: if that's inside your class declaration, it's wrong. It should be `Token addToken(std::string name);`.

Comment: I removed _Tokenizer::_ but in not helped. Anyway the right answer is your comment under my question.